# Is there a standard library implementation of MPI inverse matrix calculation problem?

Tags: matrix, mpi, inversion

Is MPI implementation of matrix inversion a standard library routine or good MPI implementation critically depends on your setup(software/hardware) so have to be coded by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ScaLAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/) provides implementations of lots of linear algebra functionality, including the solution to least squares problems. See for example [the ScaLAPACK users' guide](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node45.html#SECTION04322000000000000000). (I don't think ScaLAPACK has a general matrix inverse - hopefully your application needs the inverse only to solve a linear system - in which case, using the functionality to do that directly will be more accurate than attempting to find an inverse).